# APiPlatform Put return object of objects instead of array on oneToMany relation

Tags: api, symfony, one-to-many, api-platform.com

I have entities Question and Choice.
Question have many Choices (oneToMany relation).
GET and PUT calls don't return the same response for entity choice.

GET on entity with oneToMany relation return array as expected =>

```
    "choices": [
                  {
                    "@id": "/choices/76913730-f8f3-4e09-8256-7f3d80273715",
                    "@type": "Choice",
                    "id": "76913730-f8f3-4e09-8256-7f3d80273715",
                    "name": "a",
                    "correct": false,
                    "columnIndex": 0,
                    "rowIndex": 0,
                    "positionInText": ""
                  },
                  {
                    "@id": "/choices/03c52c2c-6c70-4e73-8210-dd6d9f42b0b7",
                    "@type": "Choice",
                    "id": "03c52c2c-6c70-4e73-8210-dd6d9f42b0b7",
                    "name": "Aucune bonne réponse",
                    "correct": false,
                    "columnIndex": 0,
                    "rowIndex": 0,
                    "positionInText": ""
                  }
                ]
```

But not PUT =>

```
    "choices": {
                  "2": {
                    "@id": "/choices/da87269e-292d-4485-9597-6d181d7dfb89",
                    "@type": "Choice",
                    "id": "da87269e-292d-4485-9597-6d181d7dfb89",
                    "name": "a",
                    "correct": false,
                    "columnIndex": 0,
                    "rowIndex": 0,
                    "positionInText": ""
                  },
                  "3": {
                    "@id": "/choices/7a56df2f-0921-4e89-9083-faeb6e5be0ae",
                    "@type": "Choice",
                    "id": "7a56df2f-0921-4e89-9083-faeb6e5be0ae",
                    "name": "b",
                    "correct": false,
                    "columnIndex": 0,
                    "rowIndex": 0,
                    "positionInText": ""
                  },
                  "4": {
                    "@id": "/choices/84618de4-8433-4d5f-85cc-7081efe191a5",
                    "@type": "Choice",
                    "id": "84618de4-8433-4d5f-85cc-7081efe191a5",
                    "name": "Aucune bonne réponse",
                    "correct": false,
                    "columnIndex": 0,
                    "rowIndex": 0,
                    "positionInText": ""
                  }
                }
```

How to get array in PUT call too ?
Here the relation

```
    /**
         * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Choice::class, mappedBy="question", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
         * @Groups({"get_question", "post_question", "put_question", "get_exam", "post_exam", "put_exam", "get_exam_student"})
         */
        private $choices;
```

Thx

Comment: it is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62944819/symfony-4-4-serializer-problem-when-one-or-more-items-from-entitys-array-collec/62979916#62979916)